# Nâo consigo mostrar html no meio do php

Tags: php, html, css

Estou tentando inserir um carrinho que está em `html` em uma página `php`, o código inserido fora do `php` mostra o carrinho normalmente.
A biblioteca com o `css` é invocada corretamente porque monta o carrinho quando colocado fora, gostaria de entender o que pode estar acontecendo.
Já tentei colocar o código embutido no meio do `php` escapando as `aspas` e nem assim deu resultado.

O código que estou tentando inserir o html é esse:

```
//MOSTRAR CARRINHO DE COMPRA
function carrinho(){
    //VERIFICAR SE EXISTE UMA SESSION
    if ($_SESSION){
        //SEPARAR NOME DE QUANTIDADE OU VALORES
        foreach($_SESSION as $nome => $quantidade){
                // VERIFICAR SE A QUANTIDADE NÃO ESTÁ ZERADA
            if ($quantidade > 0){
                    if(substr($nome,0,9) == 'produtos_'){

                    // Pegar ID da Session
                    $id = substr($nome,9,(strlen($nome) -9));                           

                    // MONTAR O CARRINHO
                    $PD = mysql_query("SELECT 
                                            `produtos`.id_produto, 
                                            `produtos`.`status`,
                                            `produtos`.nome,
                                            `produtos`.codigo_empresa                                               
                                            FROM
                                            `produtos`
                                            WHERE
                                            `produtos`.id_produto = '".mysql_real_escape_string( (int) $id)."' ");

                    while($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($PD)) {
                            $QTD = $quantidade;

                    ?>  

                        <div class="container">
                          <form class="cartContent clearfix" method="post" action="#">
                            <div id="cartContent"> 
                              <div class="item head"> <span class="cart_img"></span> <span class="product_name fsize13 bold">PRODUTO</span> <span class="remove_item fsize13 bold"></span> <span class="total_price fsize13 bold">TOTAL</span> <span class="qty fsize13 bold">QUANTITY</span>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="item">
                                <div class="cart_img"><img src="../assets/images/demo/shop/1.jpg" alt="" width="60" /></div>
                                <a href="shop-page-full-product.html" class="product_name"><span>Man shirt XL</span> </a> 
                                <a href="#" class="remove_item"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                                <div class="qty">
                                  <input type="text" value="1" name="total" maxlength="3" id="total" />
                                  </span></div>
                                <div class="qty">
                                  <input type="text" value="1" name="valor_unitario" maxlength="3" id="valor_unitario" />
                                  &times;

                                  <input type="text" value="1" name="quantidade" maxlength="3" id="quantidade" />

                                </div>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                          </form>
                        </div>  
                      <?php         
                    }//while
                }//if prod
            }// if qtd
        }//foreach
    }// if session
```

Conteúdo da variável $list:

```
Array ( [id_produto] => 1417 [status] => 1 [nome] => MANCAL DO PI NO DA BALANÇA Ø 50MM SEM TRAVA [codigo_empresa] => RO 0245 )
```

Comment: primeira verificação a ser feita, está entrando no WHILE?

Comment: Olá @ThiagoSantos, sim, está entrando no while.

Comment: Como está tua variável `$list` assim que entra no while?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver essa situação, por descuido meu não tinha percebido que havia mais um `form` em minha página, causando assim conflito e não permitindo a renderização correta tá página.
Problema resolvido.